# How do i listen for "new blob in storage" event?

Tags: node.js, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm trying to use Azure IoT Hub Device SDK for Node to listen to *new blob in storage account* events (or whatever that's called officialy). I'm following [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device.js).

I have receive notifications turned on:

[image: portal screenshot]

However, the client SDK gets nothing when i add a file to that container.

```
client.on('message', function (msg) {
   // message event does not fire
   console.log('Id: ' + msg.messageId + ' Body: ' + msg.data);
}
```

If i send a cloud-to-device message (also from the Portal blade) it goes through just fine and i can read it in `console.log()`.

Am i listening for the completely wrong event — `message`?

Comment: Wait a second, is there a delay before blob storage fires off a "hey new blob!" event and gets picked up by IoT Hub? Like in an Azure Functions blob binding? I'll be honest i've waited less than a minute, but i can fight my ADD if i'm doing it right.

Comment: Check out this example instead: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/device_blob_upload.js, it shows how to trigger and monitor the blob upload from the device's perspective. Now, to monitor the upload from the back-end perspective, you need to use the Service client and use this other sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/service/samples/receive_file_notifications.js

Comment: Looks like i have this all backwards. I'm trying to upload a file from the backend into blob storage and expecting to get a notification on all (or specific) devices so i can trigger some work on the device. Should i just use an Azure Function with blob trigger and call the cloud-to-device messaging APIs myself from function code?

Comment: @evilSnobu, That's the different case, when the device needs to download a blob file from the cloud storage. I do recommend to use a scheduleDeviceMethod job for Azure IoT Hub, when its background process will invoke devices based on the queryCondition text to process downloading a blob file. The Azure IoT Hub job can be called by BlobTrigger Function.

Comment: is this possible for a storage account not linked to IoT hub? I couldn't find similar API in '@azure/storage-blob' or 'azure-storage' npm package.

I just logged this ticket on github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/11138 for this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're expecting to receive file upload notifications on the cloud-to-device message channel. that's not where these notifications are surfaced.

There are 2 types of SDKs for Azure IoT Hub: *Device* SDKs, and *Service* SDKs.

- The capability to *upload a file* is in the *Device SDK* (**azure-iot-device** package).
- The capability to *monitor file upload notifications (from all devices)* is in the *Service SDK* (**azure-iothub** package).

In the *Device* SDK  When the upload is complete, the callback to the `uploadToBlob` method is called.

[source from example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/device_blob_upload.js)

```
var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
var fs = require('fs');

var filePath = '[path/to/file]';
var client = Client.fromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, Protocol);
fs.stat(filePath, function (err, fileStats) {
  var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

  client.uploadToBlob('testblob.txt', fileStream, fileStats.size, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error uploading file: ' + err.constructor.name + ': ' + err.message);
    } else {
      console.log('Upload successful - ' + result);
    }
    fileStream.destroy();
  });
});
```

If you want to listen for notification when a file is uploaded to a blob by a device, you need to use the *Service* SDK . Use the client to get a "file notification receiver" and then listen on this object's "message" event.

[source for the example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/service/samples/receive_file_notifications.js)

```
var Client = require('azure-iothub').Client;
var client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

client.open(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
  } else {
    console.log('Client connected');

    client.getFileNotificationReceiver(function(err, receiver) {
      if(err) {
        console.error('Could not get file notification receiver: ' + err.message);
      } else {
        receiver.on('message', function(msg) {
          console.log('File uploaded: ');
          console.log(msg.data.toString());
          receiver.complete(msg, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              console.error('Could not complete the message: ' + err.message);
            } else {
              console.log('Message completed');
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @pierreca-MSFT, there is also another option for upload file notifications such as using an **Azure Event Grid** (today in the preview). In this case, your files are uploaded into the **event-driven blob storage**, which automatically it will publish an event message to the Event Grid. These event messages can be distributed (pushed) to the subscribers in the reliable manner based on the Event Grid Subscriptions. This is an event-driven push model.

More details about the Azure Event Grid is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview) and for event-driven blob storage [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview).

The following screen snippet shows an example of the event message in my subscriber (Azure Function) after when the file has been uploaded from the device. Note, that for this example (for demonstration purpose), the device used a REST Api calls for handling an upload file, see more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/httpruntime).

[image]